# UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION while integrating a library project

Tags: android, android-studio, dhis-2

I am trying to integrate [DHIS2 SDK](https://github.com/dhis2/dhis2-android-sdk) into my app by trying to import the library project.

My `settings.gradle` looks like

```
include ':app', ':sdk', ':core', ':persistence', ':core-java', ':models'
project(':sdk').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../dhis2-android-sdk-master/app')
project(':core').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../dhis2-android-sdk-master/core')
project(':persistence').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../dhis2-android-sdk-master/persistence')
project(':core-java').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../dhis2-android-sdk-master/core-java')
project(':models').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../dhis2-android-sdk-master/models')
```

Now after the gradle sync when I try to run the app it gives me the following build error

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
... 12 more
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: your jdk compat settings are what? it will be in yoru app build script in the android block

Comment: For my project gradle I haven't mentioned anything. In the library project's gradle it's version 1.7